# Meteor.js - can't access value in database

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have slight problem which I cannot overcome.
I'm using Accounts.ui package and I'm trying to make email verification.
After registration I call method `sendVerificationEmail`, mail goes through and changes value `verified` in database as true and after this point I'm in trouble, I can't get client to read it.
Method I used for other value in same database is:

```
login: function(){ return Meteor.user().login };
```

but when I try to get value of `Meteor.user().emails.verified` I get undefined value.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emails is an array.

```
Meteor.user().emails[0].login
```

[Reference](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_users)

Comment: Wow I can't believe I didn't come up with that. Thanks a lot